# Infinite function on measure zero set

Tags: measure-theory, integration, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to prove that given a set $E$ of measure 0, and a function $f \equiv \infty$ on $E$, then $\displaystyle \int_{E}f = 0$.

This would be easy if one is allowed to assume that $\infty \times 0 = 0$ (at least I think so). Is this possible to prove without that?

Comment: How do you define the integral of a nonnegative function on $E$?

Comment: I see now the apparent stupidity of my question! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have one more question on this. Is $f \equiv \infty$ a measurable function?

Comment: How do you define measurable function?

Comment: Let me be more precise. What I really wanted to ask was what is the pre-image of $\{\infty\}$. For if that pre-image is a subset of $E$ then the pre-image is measurable hence we conclude that $f$ is as well. It seems to me that the pre-image is $E$ itself. Is that so?